# Use the Mean Value Theorem to show the following inequality:

Tags: real-analysis

Use the MVT to show the following inequality:

$\sqrt{1+x} \le 1+x/2,$ for all $ x \ge -1$.

I'm not quite sure how to use the MVT to show this. The original way I thought of doing this is to show that $d/dx$LHS $\le$ $d/dxRHS$ for all x $\ge 1$, and that at x = 0 both sides are equal. I don't know how to show that the LHS is less than the RHS for $x \in (-1,0)$.

I also thought of the way to solve this by just squaring both sides and simplifying - super easy I think but doesnt use MVT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$, $x\ge -1$. Then $f'(x) = \frac 1 {2\sqrt{1+x}}$. Now, for any $x \ge 0$, by the MVT, there exists $t\in (0,x)$ such that $f(x) - f(0) = f'(t)x$. And since $f'(t)\le 1/2$ for $t\ge 0$, we have $\sqrt{1+x} = f(x) = f(0) + xf'(t)\le 1 + x/2$.

EDIT: For $-1\le x < 0$, choose Kf-Sansoo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x} - \dfrac{x}{2}-1 $ on $(-1,0)$, and we have:$f'(c) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1+c}}- \dfrac{1}{2}> 0$ on $(x,0)$. Thus $f(x) =-(f(0) - f(x) )= -(0-x)f'(c)= xf'(c)< 0$, proving the claim.